# Twitter API - Efficient way to get followers lists for accounts with few million followers

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi, twitterapi-python

My challenge is to fetch all the list of followers of an account with over 30 million followers.

Currently i'm using the `GET followers/list` endpoint on Twitter's REST API, however, with the rate limiting of the free API this takes lots of days to achieve.

I am willing to pay Twitter for Premium API access, however I could not find any data suggesting that the Premium API has the necessary endpoints and sufficient rate limiting to help resolve this task in a matter of hours at the most.

Would appreciate any insight on this matter...

Comment: You could request enterprise access t.co/enterpriseaccess but generally the followers API is otherwise limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get 1 000 000 followers (or friends) within about 6 hours with public API like this :

**1st step:** get followers or friends ids with [GET followers/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids) or [GET friends/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids). The rate limit is 15 requests in 15 mn to get 5000 user id per request. This is 1 request each minute then 200 mn to get 1,000,000 user ids *(3h20mn)*

**2nd step:** convert user ids to user names (screen names) with [GET users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup). The rate limit is 900 requests within 15 mn to convert 100 user ids per request. So 100 users per second, this is 1,000,000 users in 10,000 s *(2h46mn)*

Total : 6h06 to get 1,000,000 screen names of followers (or friends)

With premium API it seems there is no rate limiting so it should be faster (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting)...

Comment: I am trying to get follower list of Twitter user, can you please guide me? Here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script